# Pack docker image as executable `exe` file

Tags: windows, docker

I have a docker image that has a web server in it. I want users to be able to run it without suffering through docker installation or learning the commands.

An ideal user experience would be to just have `exe` file they can run (docker image should start). Normal installer that produces icon on desktop is another option.

Is that possible on current technological level?

Comment: You would need an installer taking care of installing or providing a full-scale docker installation wrapped into that exe file, not sure it's a good idea

Comment: we ship containarised software inside images, why not bundle further the image with standalone docker :D

Comment: Not sure whether this is a genius and/or terrible idea but it's definitely worth a try!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, or any other feasible approaches?

Comment: Nope, I think technology is not there yet

Comment: Is technology there yet _now_?

Comment: I am also trying to figure out how to bundle docker (or, preferably podman, or a business-friendlier version of qemu) so a containerized linux app can "just work" with one or two clicks on windows.